# What does the asterisk mean in rspec output

Tags: ruby, rspec

What does the asterisk mean in rspec output?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-13-166:~/bridge_interfac$ bundle exec rspec spec
..................................*.*F.........................*.......*.................*...........................^C
Exiting... Interrupt again to exit immediately.
.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This mean test `pending`.

> RSpec offers a number of different ways to indicate that an example is
>   disabled pending some action.

In this test have pending method:

```
describe "an example" do
  it "is a pending some action"
end
```